# Pyspark- Assign each group in groupBy an ID

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to assign each group in a groupby a unique id number starting from 0 or 1 and incrementing by 1 for each group using pyspark.

I have done this previously using pandas with python with the command:

```
df['id_num'] = (df
                .groupby('column_name')
                .grouper
                .group_info[0])
```

A toy example of the input and desired output is:

Input

```
+------+
|object|
+------+
|apple |
|orange|
|pear  |
|berry |
|apple |
|pear  |
|berry |
+------+
```

output:

```
+------+--+
|object|id|
+------+--+
|apple |1 |
|orange|2 |
|pear  |3 |
|berry |4 |
|apple |1 |
|pear  |3 |
|berry |4 |
+------+--+
```

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure if the order is important. If not you can use dense_rank window function in this case

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.window import Window
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F
>>> 
>>> df.show()
+------+
|object|
+------+
| apple|
|orange|
|  pear|
| berry|
| apple|
|  pear|
| berry|
+------+
>>> 
>>> df.withColumn("id", F.dense_rank().over(Window.orderBy(df.object))).show()
+------+---+
|object| id|
+------+---+
| apple|  1|
| apple|  1|
| berry|  2|
| berry|  2|
|orange|  3|
|  pear|  4|
|  pear|  4|
+------+---+
```

Comment: The order itself doesn't matter, once it increments per group it's fine.

Comment: What happens if you have data partitioned? I get the warning: `WARN  WindowExec:66 - No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.`

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, create_map, lit
from itertools import chain
values = [('apple',),('orange',),('pear',),('berry',),('apple',),('pear',),('berry',)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(values,['object'])

#Creating a column of distinct elements and converting them into dictionary with unique indexes.
df1 = df.distinct()
distinct_list = list(df1.select('object').toPandas()['object'])
dict_with_index = {distinct_list[i]:i+1 for i in range(len(distinct_list))}

#Applying the mapping of dictionary.
mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*dict_with_index.items())])
df=df.withColumn("id", mapping_expr.getItem(col("object")))
df.show()
+------+---+
|object| id|
+------+---+
| apple|  2|
|orange|  1|
|  pear|  3|
| berry|  4|
| apple|  2|
|  pear|  3|
| berry|  4|
+------+---+
```